# R - class AsIs will not work with sf package

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, r-sf

I am working with .shp files in Spotfire and when I save it, the geometry data is saved with the class "AsIs".  Using the sf package and the function st_as_sfc (so that I can perform other functions) I get the following error message that is shown below.  I recreated it in the example below.

How do I convert Geometry to something sf can work with, or more specifically what class?

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)

class(nc$geometry) <- "AsIs"
st_as_sfc(nc$geometry)

Error in UseMethod("st_as_sfc") :
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sfc' applied to an object of class "AsIs"*
```

Comment: You can assign the class attribute directly `attr( nc$geometry, "class" ) <- c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc")`  . This relies on knowing the geometry type (MULTIPOLYGON) in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  That does change the class but seem to corrupt the data frame because it won't open.  This is the error.                                                                      
  `Error in st_sfc(unclass(x)[i], crs = st_crs(x), precision = st_precision(x)) : 
  is.numeric(crs) || is.character(crs) || inherits(crs, "crs") is not TRUE`

Comment: I don't get that error on the example in your question. Can you update your question with an example that reproduces this error?

Comment: Thank you again for look at this.  I believe the problem is the format in which I get the data, I just don't know how to reformat it to work in sf.  I ultimately want to use st_intersect function.  Here is the data.                                                                                                                                 (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehA8HbL21Wmob-_kx3ilAKo3LwQTBLtN) `load("sec_shp.RData")
attr( sec_shp$Geometry, "class" ) <- c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc")
View(sec_shp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual data isn't quite like the example in your question.

The geometry is represented as  Well-Known Binary in raw format

```r
library(sf)

load("~/Downloads/sec_shp.RData")


sec_shp$Geometry[[1]]
# [1] 01 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 0f d5 78 9b 80 63 59 c0 bb 0f 16 3b dd 1e 40 40 79 1f cd 16 3c 63 59 c0 04 bf
# [40] e8 1a 19 1d 40 40 d0 8f b7 4d 3b 63 59 c0 b5 71 ce eb 13 1d 40 40 44 a3 aa 2a 49 64 59 c0 dc 03 be fe 9b 1c 40 40 42
# [79] d0 d2 eb 8e 64 59 c0 65 05 c1 d3 64 1e 40 40 0f d5 78 9b 80 63 59 c0 bb 0f 16 3b dd 1e 40 40
```

which you can read using

```
sf:::st_as_sfc.raw( sec_shp$Geometry[[1]] )
# Geometry set for 1 feature 
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -101.5712 ymin: 32.22351 xmax: -101.5505 ymax: 32.24113
# CRS:            NA
# POLYGON ((-101.5547 32.24113, -101.5505 32.2273...
```

So to read this all in one go, set the class to be `WKB` and then call `st_as_sfc()`

```
attr(sec_shp$Geometry, "class") <- c("WKB")

sfc <- sf::st_as_sfc( sec_shp$Geometry )

sec_shp$Geometry <- sfc

sf <- sf::st_as_sf( sec_shp )
```

And you're done

---

I was keen to see what your data looked like, so here it is

```
library(mapdeck)

set_token( secret::get_secret( "mapbox" ) )

mapdeck() %>%
  add_polygon(
    data = sf
    , fill_colour = "OBJECTID"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't recognize that the format was different that what I originally submitted.  I know now how to check for it.  The solution is perfect, thank you for taking the time.